# Increment field whenever duplicate is prevented in UNION'ed query

Tags: mysql

I have multiple SELECT queries unioned.  The composite primary key is preventing duplicates, which is what I want.  Is there a way to increment a certain field whenever a duplicate row is prevented from being inserted from one of the unioned queries?

Comment: Are you specifying `UNION ALL`?  By default `UNION` is `DISTINCT`...

Comment: No, I want the results to be distinct.  I just want to know about any duplicate prevented.

Comment: My misunderstanding.  See my proposed answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UNION ALL` to retain the duplicates, then group the result with an outer query:

```
SELECT a, b, c, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, c FROM ...
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a, b, c FROM ...
) AS t
GROUP BY a, b, c
```